# PostgreSQL 9.5 Select only non matching records from two tables

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables representing some geographical datas and :
- one with the actual datas,
- one storing the name of the streets,
- one storing the combination between the street number and the street name (table address).

I already have some address existing in my table, in order to realize an INSERT INTO SELECT in a fourth table, I am looking on how to build the SELECT query to retrieve only the objects not already existing in the address table.

I tried different approaches, including the NOT EXISTS and the id_street IS NULL conditions, but I didn't manage to make it work.

Here is an example : http://rextester.com/KMSW4349

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `EXCEPT` to remove the rows already in `address`:

```
INSERT INTO address(street_number,id_street)
   SELECT DISTINCT datas.street_number, street.id_street
   FROM datas
   LEFT JOIN street USING (street_name)
EXCEPT
   SELECT street_number, id_street FROM address;
```

You could end up with duplicates if there are concurrent data modifications on `address`.

To avoid that, you'd add a unique constraint and use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "concurrent data modifications" ?

Comment: If somebody inserts a row in `address` while your query is running, the `SELECT` after the `EXCEPT` won't see the new row yet. After both transactions are done, you have two rows with the same `street_number` and `id_street`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. This won't happen in my case since I will only populate a table once.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query is not correct. You have to match with the outer tables:

```
INSERT INTO address(street_number,id_street)
SELECT DISTINCT street_number, id_street
FROM datas
LEFT JOIN street ON street.street_name=datas.street_name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM address a2 WHERE a2.street_number = datas.street_number AND a2.id_street = street.id_street);
```